# Best way to create date object from unformatted string

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have the following string which represents a date: `'20200317'` (yyyyMMdd). Is there any way to pass this string directly to a date object in python? Or I'll have to "break" this string into the year, month and day and then pass it to the date object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```py
from datetime import datetime
datetimeObject = datetime.strptime('20200317', '%Y%m%d')
```